# Make FreeRDP prompt user for username and password?

Tags: remote, remote-desktop, freerdp

At the moment, I'm using the following command to start an FreeRDP session:

```
$ sudo xfreerdp /v:farm.company.com /d:company.com \
    /u:oshiro /p:oshiro_password /g:rds.company.com
```

Works fine.  However, I don't want the password to be in the command line like that.  So I tried it without the password:

```
$ sudo xfreerdp /v:farm.company.com /d:company.com /u:oshiro /g:rds.company.com
```

And I got a connection failure message instead of some sort of dialog box or prompt asking me to enter in a password.

Is it possible to get this to prompt the user for a password?

---

**UPDATE: Omitting the `/p` switch**

Without the `/p` switch, I get the following:

```
oshiro@ubuntu:~$ xfreerdp /v:farm.company.com /d:company.com -u:oshiro /g:rds.company.com
connected to rds.company.com:443
connected to rds.company.com:443
Could not open SAM file!
Could not open SAM file!
Could not open SAM file!
Could not open SAM file!
rts_connect error! Status Code: 401
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="rds.company.com"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 23 Mar 2014 10:40:30 GMT +12
Content-Length: 13

rts_connect error!
rpc_connect failed!
Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
```

Comment: What version of xfreerdp do you have? In Debian wheezy with freerdp-x11 1.0.1, as far as I can tell from the source (I have no RDP server handy to check), there is a password prompt.

Comment: I have version 1.2.0-beta1.

Comment: Why the heck are you using `sudo`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick is putting the password switch at the end of your command line so that you can leave it blank. This will trigger `xfreerdp` to prompt your for the password instead of having to provide it via the command line.

#### Example

*new cli interface (v1.1+)*

```
$ xfreerdp /v:farm.company.com /d:company.com /u:oshiro /g:rds.company.com /p
```

*old cli interface (v1.0.2)*

```
$ xfreerdp -u oshiro -d company.com farm.company.com -t 3389 -p
```

**NOTE:** The new CLI is available in the pre-releases, v1.1+, so pay special attention to which version you're using. Running the command `xfreerdp --version` will show you which. Also take a look at the [releases topic](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/releases) in the wiki for more information on each.

#### Sample connection

Here's an example of me connecting to a RDP server.

```
$ xfreerdp --ignore-certificate -u smingolelli -d mydom -t 5000 rdp.mydom.com -p
connected to rdp.mydom.com:5000
Password:
```

#### Prompting the user

This issue in the FreeRDP issue tracker titled: [Prompt for Credentials - NLA #1512](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/1512), had this snippet of how you could use `zenity` to prompt the user for a username and password using GUI dialogs and then run `xfreerdp` with the provided info afterwards.

```
$ xfreerdp /v:yourRDSfarmFQDN \
/u:$(zenity \
--entry \
--title="Domain Username" \
--text="Enter your Username") \
/p:$(zenity \
--entry \
--title="Domain Password" \
--text="Enter your _password:" \
--hide-text) \
/d:yourdomainname \
/f \
/cert-ignore
+clipboard
```

The above when executed would pop these dialogs up to the user. These will come up one at a time in turn.

[image: ss #1]         [image: ss #2]

#### References

- [Commnad Line Interfaces - FreeRDP Wiki](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/CommandLineInterface)

Comment: Thanks for this.  However, when I try `xfreerdp /v:farm.company.com /d:company.com /u:oshiro /g:rds.company.com /p`, it just gives me the documentation and all the commands I could use.  Then as soon as I put the password after the `p` it starts working.

Comment: @oshirowanen - if you omit the `/p` switch all together?

Comment: The error was too long to post as a comment, so I have updated the original question with the error message.

Comment: @oshirowanen - that looks like it might be a bug: https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/1584. Shows the same output as yours. I would open an issue with FreeRDP, if you're not sure how to do this I can assist further LMK.

Comment: instead of `zenity --entry --text="Enter your _password:" --hide-text` you can simply say `zenity --password`

Comment: @user829755 - the use of `--password` has been problematic, not working on specific versions of zenity, hence why I showed this method here.

Comment: For the `zenith` version: I think it is worth noting that the password in the command line is hidden after start (by `xfreerdp` I suppose) and is not visible after that. But there should be a short amount of time where it could be observed by other users of the machine.

Answer (score 7):

If you specify tls security, the remote computer will prompt for password:

```
Xfreerdp --sec tls
```

The new parameter format:

```
  /sec:tls
```

Comment: This answer still works in 2020 and doesn't need an additional tool/command. This should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, this is an invitation to the login screen. It helped me, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to expand on [slm's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm) [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119880/make-freerdp-prompt-user-for-username-and-password/120976#120976).  I wanted a single window to enter all information in and allow me to specify a RemoteApp all in one go, so I built on what he suggested with zenity and created this.

**XFreeRDP Prompt**

[image: XFreeRDP-Prompt]

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# XFreeRDP RemoteApp W/ Prompt Script
# Version 0.3
# Description:
# XFreeRDP Remote App Script utilizing Zentity to populate variables
# Written by Jarrett Higgins 12-2015

OUTPUT=$(zenity --forms --title="Connection Information" \
    --text="Enter information about your Remote Connection" \
    --separator="," \
    --add-entry="Server" \
    --add-entry="Port (Default: 3389)" \
    --add-entry="Domain (Optional)" \
    --add-entry="Username" \
    --add-password="Password" \
    --add-entry="Remote App Name (Optional)")
OUTPUT_RESULTS=$?
if ((OUTPUT_RESULTS != 0)); then
    echo "something went wrong"
    exit 1
fi
Blank=""
Server=$(awk -F, '{print $1}' <<<$OUTPUT)
Port=$(awk -F, '{print $2}' <<<$OUTPUT)
if ["$Port" = "$Blank"]
then
    Port="3389"
else
    Port="$Port"
fi
Domain=$(awk -F, '{print $3}' <<<$OUTPUT)
Username=$(awk -F, '{print $4}' <<<$OUTPUT)
Password=$(awk -F, '{print $5}' <<<$OUTPUT)
App=$(awk -F, '{print $6}' <<<$OUTPUT)
if ["$App" = "$Blank"]
then
    App="$App"
    Title="$Server"
else
    AppName="$App"
    Title="$AppName on $Server"
    App="/app:||$App"
fi
#zenity --info --title="Information Return" --text="$Server $Port $Domain $Username $Password $App"
xfreerdp /t:"$Title" /v:$Server:$Port /d:$Domain /u:$Username /p:$Password $App /cert-ignore /workarea +clipboard
Password=""
```

**Features:**

- Defaults to port 3389 if not populated
- Defaults to no Remote App if not populated

**Planned:**

- Security Certificate Warning
- RDWeb Query to provide Resource List

I use this on my #!++ laptop with great success for connecting to my company and VM Remote Apps and client Servers.  I'm not experienced with scripting, so if anyone has any suggestions or feedback, I would love to hear them.

Comment: instead of the compare with $Blank you can use [ -z "$var" ]. Also there's no need to unset the password at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I also like yad, using the following shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
frmdata=$(yad --title "Connect to remote computer" --form --field="Remote computer" --field="Username" --field="Password:H" --field="Domain" --field="Gateway")
frmcomputer=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $1 }')
frmusername=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $2 }')
frmpassword=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $3 }')
frmdomain=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $4 }')
frmgateway=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $5 }')
xfreerdp /v:$frmcomputer /f /d:$frmdomain /u:$frmusername /g:$frmgateway /p:$frmpassword /cert-ignore
```

It provides a good interface, and hides the password.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply an empty parameter (without password value). Try this:

```
sudo xfreerdp /v:farm.company.com /d:company.com /u:oshiro /g:rds.company.com /p
```

If that does not work, then you could accomplish this with simple bash script.

Save this as `rdp.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Read Password
echo -n Password: 
read -s password
echo
# Run Command
sudo xfreerdp /v:farm.company.com /d:company.com /u:oshiro /g:rds.company.com /p:$password
```

Then make file executable:

```
chmod +x rdp.sh
```

Launch it:

```
./rdp.sh
```

This has been asked and discussed more thoroughly on xfreerdp's github issue: https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/1358

The bash script idea is taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing

Comment: This exposes the password to users doing `ps -ef`.

Comment: Why are you using sudo here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use --from-stdin as well. Then you will be prompted for any needed values that were not provided.

I liked Jarretts solution but with yad not zenity, it lets you do combo boxes:

```
OUTPUT=$(yad --center --button="gtk-ok:0" --title "Remote Desktop" --form \
--field="Server:CB" "rds1.domain.local\!rds2.domain.local\!rds3.domain.local" \
--field="Port" "3389" \
--field="Domain" "DOMAIN.local" \
--field="Username" "" \
--field="Password:H" \
--field="Remote App Name" "")
```

Comment: In my case, this was the simple solution to getting xfreerdp to prompt for the password.

xfreerdp /v:192.168.30.25:15000 /u:sean /from-stdin:force